# Port on remote server appears open from one server but no the other

Tags: networking, postgresql

So this one has been a bit odd. I have a server within my work VPN that has postgres setup on it. I can access the server in question from my local WSL instance (when connected to the vpn obv) and from other server within the network at the datacenter but not from one server in particular thats at the office (also part of the VPN). However this server can still ssh and detect other open ports on the postgres server.

On the postgres server I can see the port is open and available for all hosts.
I've checked ufw, firewalld and iptables and see nothing that would interfere.

I'm really at a total loss here, my guess is something blocking the server from office but am not sure how I would check it.

Comment: sounds like traffic passing from the office over the VPN is passing through a network firewall that has not been configured to pass traffic for that port. I'd check with the network infrastructure folks.

Comment: Thats what I figure as well. Is there any way to test this though? Unfortunately our networking guy is no longer with us and we dont have a new one yet....

Comment: you can try to narrow down the point of failure, but you won't really be able to do anything without being able to access the blocking system, get into it, and configure it, so there probably isn't too much that can be done until you get the new network guy. hopefully the old guy left good documentation.